# Google Map - change style attributes for an existing marker and update map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In Google map one could create a map and place a custom marker as follows

```
let lat = 19.29;
let long = 72.85;
let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 12});
let LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: LatLng,
                    map: map,
                    icon: { path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                            scale: 2,
                            fillColor: 'Crimson',
                            strokeColor: 'Crimson'                          
                          }
                });
```

How do we change the marker style later on, `fillColor` for example ?

This question is different from the one marked as a duplicate of - this one is generic about updating style attributes of an existing marker and specific to google map api v3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the current icon from the marker, change its color, set the new icon:

```
var icon = marker.getIcon();
icon.fillColor = "#00FF00";
icon.strokeColor = "#00FF00";
marker.setIcon(icon);
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xjnp0kbv/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var color = ["#FF0000", "#00FF00", "#0000FF"];
var colorIdx = 1;

function initialize() {

  let lat = 19.29;
  let long = 72.85;
  let LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
  let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: LatLng
  });
  let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: LatLng,
    map: map,
    icon: {
      path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
      scale: 10,
      fillColor: 'Crimson',
      strokeColor: 'Crimson'
    }
  });
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('btn'), 'click', function() {
    var icon = marker.getIcon();
    icon.fillColor = color[colorIdx];
    icon.strokeColor = color[colorIdx];
    colorIdx++;
    colorIdx %= color.length;
    marker.setIcon(icon);
  })
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="change color" />
<div id="map"></div>
```